# CoreData not saving attribute as string

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Below is my saving method

```
-(void)createData
{
    //    // get date and time and store in two separate variables
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    NSLog(@"Date is: %@",dateString);
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
    NSString *timeString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    NSLog(@"Time is: %@",timeString);
    //
    //

    ReminderInfo *reminderInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ReminderInfo" inManagedObjectContext:[DataManager sharedDataManager].managedObjectContext];

    reminderInfo.date = today;
    reminderInfo.reminderTime = @"06:30";
    reminderInfo.medicationType = @"Cream";
    [[DataManager sharedDataManager] saveReminderInfo:reminderInfo];
    NSLog(@"reminder created");

}
```

Below is the output from console:

```
<ReminderInfo: 0x6080002887a0> (entity: ReminderInfo; id: 0xd000000000480002 <x-coredata://8055FB8D-6E6A-44B2-9456-3E6932ACBE32/ReminderInfo/p18> ; data: {
    date = "2017-06-03 08:03:40 +0000";
    medicationType = Cream;
    reminderTime = "06:30";
})
```

medicationType is an attribute with `String` type. As you can see from the console, there isn't any `""` in `Cream`. Could this be the reason im not saving anything to coredata?

Comment: no, it can't be

Answer (score 0):

Try and declare the "cream" as a string first.

ie `NSString *medType = @"Cream";`
and then in the save method use the medType.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of quote marks there has nothing to do with the data type. When printing a Core Data object to the Xcode console, quote marks are not used if there are no spaces in the string. What you are seeing is exactly what would be expected for the string you're using. If you changed the string to `@"Cream cheese"`, you would see quote marks, but the data type would be the same. If it wasn't a string, Core Core Data would have no way to convert the value-- a numeric type maybe?-- to `Cream`.